# PHP MySQL persistent connections and free result?

Tags: php, mysql

Naturally when the PHP script ends all the MySQL query resources that have not already been manually unset with by a free result function will be freed automatically when the connection is dropped at the end of the script.

But what about with persistent connections? Are we sure that PHP will actively free all these results when the PHP script ends and we have connected to the MySQL database with a persistent connection?

Comment: what kind of 'persistent' connections are you making?

Comment: There is only one type of persistent connection, a persistent one. What type of persistent connection are you talking about?

Comment: well if you want to be like that, don't expect any help from me.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting my attitude towards your comment. I simply do not understand what you mean.

Comment: i know three ways to make a persistent connection from php using the native library alone.

Comment: OK. Well I'm specifically using `mysql_pconnect`. Though I was attempting to avoid saying that so as not to have a million people tell me that its deprecated and that I can't possibly use it.

Comment: in generally persistent connection are a bad idea, so you need to explain why your using one(or many) in the first place

Comment: Because I have a massive number of connections at any point in time and it was generally recommended to me that persistent connections are more efficient in such a circumstance.

Comment: connections are recycled, connections with the same credentials are 'shared' connections on a machine where db server and php are both located use very little resource.

Comment: @Dagon, well on my server MySQL uses 50GB of RAM alone, which it uses for a reason. You can't say it uses little resources if you don't know what it's used for.